# How to use grep command to print value of a variable in a line?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh, scripting-language

For Example,consider the below line

```
<WORKFLOWLINK CONDITION ="" FROMTASK ="Start" TOTASK ="cmd_START_RUN"/>
```

From above line, I need to print **Start** from `FROMTASK ="Start"` using grep command or using any command.

Comment: If this is about "parsing" XML then the answer is to use an xml parsing tool. Like perl, python, ruby, etc. or to use a tool like xsltproc or [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: ksh: xmllint:  not found. error

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this :

```
$ xmllint --xpath 'string(//WORKFLOWLINK/@FROMTASK)' file
Start

$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'string(//WORKFLOWLINK/@FROMTASK)' file
Start

$ saxon-lint --xpath 'string(//WORKFLOWLINK/@FROMTASK)' file
Start
```

- `xmllint` from `libxml2`
- [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)
- [saxon-lint](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint)

Comment: ksh: xmllint:  not found.

Comment: Maybe you need to install it or use another tool ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want value of `FROMTASK`, or some fixed variables try `sed`:

```
sed -nre 's/^.*FROMTASK *= *"([^"]*)".*$/\1/p' file
```

If you want to get value of any variables, try `xmllint` as [sputnick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465183/sputnick) answered

Use `sudo apt-get install libxml2-utils`(for debian) or `yum install libxml2-utils` to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Since your tags don't suggest this is about XML, simply use cut command

```
cut -d "\"" -f4
```